# JEditorPane: get class attribute of HTML element

Tags: java, html, swing, jeditorpane, htmleditorkit

So I have a JEditorPane to display a HTML page. I have written codes to retrieve an HTML element by id. I have trouble in getting the attributes of them.

For example, there is `<span id="0" class="insert">abc</span>` in HTML page. I want to get class name `insert`, given its id.

My code looks like this,

```
    HTMLDocument html = (HTMLDocument) jeditor.getDocument();
    String id = "0";

    // make sure this id exists
    if ((elem = html.getElement(id)) != null) { 
        // get the name of class in span element
        String className = (String) elem.getAttributes().getAttribute("class");
        ...
    }
```

This doesn't work. However, `elem.getAttributes()` returns me the following,

```
LeafElement(content) 15,16
```

This is not like a set of attributes of a HTML element. How should I get the class attribute of a HTML element?

Thanks!

Comment: I have given this up. I shouldn't waste my life in getting class attributes from HTML in Java.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies with the parameter you're passing to the **getAttribute** method. Instead of the string *"class"*, you have to use **HTML.Attribute.CLASS**. So, the last line of code would read:

```
String className = (String) elem.getAttributes()
                                .getAttribute(HTML.Attribute.CLASS);
```

Similar question: [How do I retrieve the attribute of an element using Swing's HTMLEditorKit.ParserCallback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767135/how-do-i-retrieve-the-attribute-of-an-element-using-swings-htmleditorkit-parser)

In case you need to deal with other attributes, have a look also at the API documentation for the [HTML.Attribute class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTML.Attribute.html).